# actions in $resource in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, resources

I have a webapi back end with the following method in the ProductController :

```
     [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/product/FindName")]
    public Product FindName(string name){
     return name & "Hello "
    }
```

I am trying to make use of $resource in the frontend.

```
var resource = $resource('api/product/:id', {});
```

resource.query() will return all items which are exposed in the server side using the GetALL() method. This works fine .

What exactly is the {action} in the $resource does ? I have seen examples for the POST, but what if is set

```
var resource = $resource('api/product/:id', {}, { FindName: { method: 'GET', params: { name: 'phone' } } });
```

will this call the method FindName in the backend ? or what exactly it does, I mean the parameter if I set the 'GET' in method.

I am calling as

```
 resource.FindName({ name: 'phone' }, function () {

    });
```

But the backend is not getting fired . i see the call that is being requested to the server from fiddler is

```
Demo/api/product?name=phone
```

Comment: I am mistaken it seems, if we need to call the server side method, then the URL in the action has to be provided  var resource = $resource('api/product/:id', {}, { FindName: { url: 'api/product/FindName', method: 'GET', params: { name: 'phone' } } }); will call the server side method.  and the actions without the url will just refer to the resource initialized and work on that .. Am i right ? so these are kind of custom methods on the resource we defined in the client side .. ??

Answer (score 0):

The resource declaration is incorrect. It should be

```
var resource = $resource('api/product/:id', {}, { FindName: { method: 'GET', params: { id: 'phone' } } });
```

This defaults the `id` placeholder to value `phone`.

For invocation now you can do

```
resource.FindName({}, function () {  //gets api/product/phone

    });
```

or override `id` part

```
resource.FindName({id:'tablet'}, function () {  //gets api/product/tablet

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resource has a built in GET function that should be able to be used without the need to define the extra `FindName` action that has been added to `$resource`.

If you changed the route on your webapi to be

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/product/{name}")]
public Product FindName(string name){
    return name & "Hello "
}
```

Then you could use resource like this to get data back from this route.

```
var resource = $resource('api/product/:id', {}, {});

resource.get({ id: 'phone' }, function () {

});
```

If you wanted the name params to match on both you could change `:id` to `:name` and in the `resource.get` change id to name also.

I hope this helps.